# Viewing POST data with Python Requests Module

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I have a this example program, but currently, it doesn't show the post data.

```
import requests

r = requests.post('https://requestb.in/12p8nqo1',data={'key':'value'})

print(r.text)
```

---

.    >>> 'ok'

---

Why doesn't print " key:value "?

Thanks

Comment: Why should  it do that?

Comment: Point your browser at https://requestb.in/12p8nqo1 and view page source. May enlightenment come.

Answer (score 1):

To access the request data you must deal with the underlying PreparedRequest object, like so:

```
import requests

r = requests.post('https://requestb.in/12p8nqo1',data={'key':'value'})
print(r.request.body)
```